# Pass values to view (and its partials) from action2 in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, api, routes, sails.js, action

I have defined a simple route to a page in `config/routes.js`, with some *locals* used in a *partial view* inside that page as follow:

**routes.js**:

```js
'get /memo': { 
    view: 'pages/memo',
    locals: {
      page: {
        title: "Memo",
        subtitle: "Prendi note veloci, crea liste e presonalizza le tue TODO List"
      }
    }
  }
```

While my **page.ejs** looks something like this:

```html
<div id="memo">
    <%- partial('../partials/title-center.ejs') %>
    <!--list-->
</div>
```

So, this works fine and I am able to retrieve *locals*'s values in the partial view.

Now, what I would like to achieve is call a controller **action2** before displaying the page, in order to pass more data (and then be able to format them in the view).

I have added a new route in `routes.js` associated with a **single action2** in `api/controllers/memo/list.js`:

```js
'get /api/v1/memo/list': { action: 'memo/list' }
```

And edited the action to return the said view:

```js
...
inputs: {

  },


  exits: {
    success: {
      responseType: 'view',
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/memo'
    }
  },


  fn: async function (inputs) {

    // All done.
    return;

  }
...
```

However calling it gives me errors on the embedded js in the partial view, because it is not able (correctly) to access the `object` (`page`) defined in the original route.
(`Removing the partial view returns no error`)

Another problem is that I can't find any example of **how to pass data between action and view** when using **actions2 syntax**, as recommend in [Sails concept](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers).

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from the controller/action2 is not sent directly to your ejs page but to the associated vue.parasails file in assets/js/pages/your_page_name.page.js; it is there you have to add your code and either call another action or pass data to the view your_page_name.ejs.

Answer (score 0):

In action2, you can get access to both `res` and `req` by using `this.res` and `this.req` respectively. For your use case you can do:

```js
return this.res.view('pages/memo', {
  // pass in as much locals as you want
  page: {
        title: "Memo",
        subtitle: "Prendi note veloci, crea liste e presonalizza le tue TODO List"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
exits: {
    success: {
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/product-type/view-product-type'
    },

},
fn: async function () {  
  return {value1: 'a', value2: 'b'};
}
```

you can also use:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {  
  return exits.success({value1: 'a', value2: 'b'});
}
```

if you want the response as html:

```
exits: {
  success: {
      statusCode: 200,
      responseType: 'htmlResponse',
      description: ''
  }
},
fn: async function(inputs, exits){
  let ejs = require('ejs');  
  let cb = function(err, html){
      if (err){
        return exits.serverError(err);
      }
      return exits.success(html);
  };
  ejs.renderFile('./views/templates/dataTables.ejs',{someData: {a: 1, b:2}}, cb);
  return cb;
}
```

**Edit:**

you can also expose server values to client `<%- exposeLocalsToBrowser({keys: ['data'] } ); %>`

then they are accessible via `window.SAILS_LOCALS`

f.e:

```
beforeMount: function() {
  this.data = window.SAILS_LOCALS['data'];
}
```

more: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals